# Localize Required and other attribute values using separate project that contain localization resources(ASP.Net Core 3.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a ASP.Net Core 3.1 web project that contains some classes with properties data annotation attributes. For example:

```
public class ResetPasswordViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} field is required")]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to localize Required attribute error message so that if language is switched to non-english it should be localized on razor page which renders it as follows:

```
<span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
```

Localization resources stored in a separate project named `Localization` that contains SharedResource.uk-UA.resx and SharedResource.cs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up to solution using next services configuration:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
                services.AddMvc()
                .AddControllersAsServices()
                .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(
                    options =>
                    {
                        options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                        {                            
                            return factory.Create(typeof(SharedResource));
                        };
                    }
                );
        }
```